# iOS Parse SDK 1.7.1 & Facebook SDK v4: Are Facebook App invites included in the Parse SDK?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, cocoapods, facebook-sdk-4.0

I know the Parse SDK integrates with the FBSDK v4 and so wondered if the Facebook App invites functionality is included in the Parse SDK?

I've installed the latest Parse SDK (1.7.1) using cocoapods, here's what my Podfile looks like:

```
pod 'Parse', '~> 1.7'
pod 'ParseUI', '~> 1.1'
pod 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4', '~> 1.7'
pod 'ParseCrashReporting', '~> 1.7'
```

When I add the pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 4.0' I get a duplicate of FBSDKAccessToken.h and .m. Deleting one of these doesn't help either so I assume it was already included in a previously installed pod somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the ShareKit pod with the main Facebook-iOS-SDK pod solved the issue